# How can i clear the concept of Encapsulating Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was reading a tutorial about programing with objective C.
I got the general idea about what is encapsulating data but the detail of it is still not clear.
Can anyone help me?? I am learning it on my own so facing a bit of problems in making my concept clear.
Thanks and Sorry in advance if its a silly question.

Comment: what details are you unclear about? OO programming is a big topic.

Comment: Encapsulating data is the main topic that i am focusing on. in that getter and setter, difference between Dot method and accessor method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encapsulation simply means that access to the internal state of an object is only permitted through a defined interface. In the case of Objective-C, this includes methods and properties. You can read a property in one of two ways:

```
[foo prop]
foo.prop
```

They are pretty much the same thing, with the  form being slightly more convenient, especially when chaining accessors (e.g., `foo.bar.baz.prop` vs `[[[foo bar] baz] prop]`). You also have two options when setting properties:

```
foo.prop = 1;
[foo setProp:1];
```

The only real difference I know of is that the dotted form (in both cases) requires knowledge of the type, whereas the method form doesn't, e.g.:

```
Foo * foo = …;
[foo setProp:1]; // OK
foo.prop = 1;    // OK

id bar = foo;
[bar setProp:1]; // OK
bar.prop = 1;    // Barf
```